# Internet Explorer 8 does not show fixed menu in responsive website

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

I am working on a teaser microsite to briefly explain responsive design to unprofessionals.

Everythings is going fine with the browser's interpretation. Also for Mobile Safari.

But as usual: Microsoft's scourge of humanity, the Internet Explorer is $*#§ing up. In this case it concerns to Version 8. For Version 9 everythings's ok.

IE 8 does not show the fixed navigation and so the user cannot slide from screen to screen.

I have been looking for a solution quite a while, but I could not find. Perhaps you can help me out.

The site can be found under:

http://www.nerdcraft-design.de/teaser/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post in fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: A fiddle is unnecessary, he has provided a working sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is just a positioning issue - IE gets confused easily so its best to be explicit - try just adding `left: 0;` to the nav :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the HTML5 shiv to register the new HTML5 elements in old IE. They will still display without it, but any CSS selectors containing these elements, in your case nav, won't apply the CSS.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

EDIT: As pointed out, you are polyfilling these elements, but it appears you have a javascript error on your page that is possibly stopping it from executing:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' 
teaser, line 50 character 3
```

Comment: A good point but this is already in place on his example (ie.js)

Comment: I saw that but I didn't realise it added support for the HTML5 elements, are you sure it does?

Comment: 100%, that's just how the the shiv works. Kinda crazy I know :). Here is some background: http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

Comment: I hadn't looked at the source for that, you're right. There is a javascript error on the page that must be preventing it from working.

Comment: still not I'm afraid. Otherwise the section element wouldn't be styled. If you have dev tools running, try out my solution :)

Comment: Thanks, Inrbob. That was the point. So now it's showing up. But for some kind of reason IE8 does not use the scrollto plugin. It must concern to the issue in line 50. I will look it up.

But anyways: Thanks to both of you for your efforts.